# In Android contact,when exactly does aggregation happen?

Tags: android, android-contacts

I added a new person into my contacts,who's name is the same with another existing person.

Then I checked them out in the raw_contacts table of the contacts2.db,and found that the contact_id of the two rows are different.And column aggregation_needed is 0.

As I found in [Android API](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/ContactsContract.RawContacts.html) aggregation should happen when I insert a record.So I'm confused.

Are there any detail documents that explain the aggregation in android contact?

Comment: To my knowledge there is no documentation about how exactly aggregation works. The ContactsProvider does some comparison and basically comes up with a score how likely it is that two contacts are actually the same contact. I imagine that logic has changed over time and may change further.

Comment: I found no docs either.It's strange that in some conditions,the aggregation_needed column is 1,which means the system knows those raw_contacts rows need aggregation,but it doesn't happen.

Answer (score 1):

Contact aggregation happens asynchronously after you add a contact.

If you add 2 contacts with the same name under same contact source then it will not automatically aggregate them (since ICS if I remember correctly)

Some additional info on the rules of aggregation :

**Automatic aggregation**

When a raw contact is added or modified, the system looks for matching (overlapping) raw contacts with which to aggregate it. It may not find any matching raw contacts, in which case it will create an aggregate contact that contains just the original raw contact. If it finds a single match,it creates a new contact that contains the two raw contacts. And it may even find multiple similar raw contacts, in which case it chooses the closest match.  Two raw contacts are considered to be a match if at least one of these conditions is met:
• They have matching names.
• Their names consist of the same words but in different order (for example, "Bob Parr" and "Parr, Bob")
• One of them has a common short name for the other (for example, "Bob Parr" and "Robert Parr")
• One of them has just a first or last name and it matches the other raw contact. This rule is less reliable, so it only applies if the two raw contacts are also sharing some other data like a phone number, an email address or a nickname (for example, Helen ["elastigirl"] = Helen Parr ["elastigirl"])
• At least one of the two raw contacts is missing the name altogether and they are sharing a phone number, an email address or a nickname (for example, Bob Parr [incredible@android.com] = incredible@android.com).

When comparing names, the system ignores upper/lower case differences (Bob=BOB=bob) and diacritical marks (Hélène=Helene). When comparing two phone numbers the system ignores special characters such as "*", "#", "(", ")", and whitespace. Also if the only difference between two numbers is that one has a country code and the other does not, then the system considers those to be a match (except for numbers in the Japan country code). Automatic aggregation is not permanent; any change of a constituent raw contact may create a new aggregate or break up an existing one.